# Do monitors not atomically/instantaneously refresh their pixels?

Tags: display, monitoring, refresh, screen-tearing

I'm trying to understand what causes screen tearing. Suppose that a monitor could update every single one of its pixels instantaneously. Then I imagine refreshes would work like this:

1. A monitor decides its going to start a refresh
2. It looks at whatever frame the GPU is currently sending it.
3. It, atomically, updates all pixels instantaneously.

With this kind of procedure, it seems like it should be completely impossible to get screen tearing, ignoring refresh rates and FPS entirely. Only a single image is drawn at a given time.

Now I know this isn't how CRT monitors work with their scanning gun (or whatever it's called). But I was under the impression that newer monitor technologies didn't work like this. Do they actually update pixels gradually, and not at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps 2 & 3 assume that all frame data is transferred to the monitor in an immediate and atomic fashion, they are not.  A "dumb" monitor never "sees" (or buffers) a full frame of video.  Monitors still work on the same principles from when we used scanning electron beams to draw pictures. Snazzier TVs might buffer images and do inter-frame processing, but a computer monitor probably won't.

What the monitor sees is merely a data stream coming from your graphics card.  There are all sorts of preliminary information sent to the monitor to tell it what format that data stream will be, so it gets details of timing information, number of horizontal lines, a number of vertical lines and colour format but what it actually gets is simply a long string of pixel colour data.

Your steps 2 & 3 actually occur in the graphics card, and step 3 will only "appear" to be the case if you enable vertical sync.

At any point in the video frame the GPU can decide to swap its video buffer to a new picture and carry on sending data from that point in the buffer. If vertical sync is not enabled then it will carry on sending the new buffer data to the monitor from the exact same point it left off in the old buffer.  This is your "tear" point.

If you have vertical sync enabled then the GPU will wait for the full frame to be sent before it switches buffer in which case you will not see a "tear".

Comment: In fact, the reason that these sync technologies are called "Vertical Sync" is that each successive frame is written vertically across even the newest monitors.

Comment: Admittedly the frame buffer order of "right to left, top to bottom" (send row, move to next column, send another row) is an easy switch to make to go to "top to bottom, right to left" (send column, move to next row, send column) given modern electronics, but vertical sync has always meant "wait for the top corner of the frame". Either way vertical sync is "start of frame" irrespective of how that frame is ordered.

Comment: @music2myear In fact I would expect the "column then row" method only to really be *noticed* in mobile phones where you are, effectively, holding the screen in the wrong orientation i.e. in portrait mode.  Once you hold the device in landscape mode (best for viewing videos) you are back to updating the screen in a row/column mode again.

Comment: And I'd really like more information on atomic screens. Will we find these in the iPhone 9?

Comment: @music2myear I thought we were going to see them in the Android Nuclear update, but apparently not.

Comment: Yea, with Nougat we just got Snickers-powered screens.

Comment: Ah! Okay. I was missing that the GPU didn't transfer the entire frame at once (in hindsight that seems obvious... would be a lot of data to send at once). I'm still a little confused though... so the GPU sends data to the monitor that amounts to "paint pixel (x,y,z) color (r,g,b)" at some rate, right? So how does the monitor's refresh rate come into this?

Comment: @Mokubai re-reading your answer + comments I think I understand: the GPU is busy generating images to display and storing them in buffers. How fast it generates these images is the "game FPS". At the same time, another process (part of the GPU as well?) is reading off pixels form the buffers and sending them to the monitor. The rate that this happens is the refresh rate?

Comment: @alecb Yes, that pretty much sums up what is happening.  The monitor has almost no ability to hold any data at all and so it just paints each pixel one after another as it is received.

Comment: @Mokubai So then what limits the refresh rate? How quickly the monitor can repaint an individual pixel times the number of pixels?

Comment: @alecb Essentially yes. Your current FullHD monitor has about 2 million pixels in three different colours meaning it needs to run through 6 million LCD adjustments *per screen refresh*.  Doing that at 60 frames per second means 360 million pixel updates per second. This is actually a very large amount of data being thrown about and a lot of physical adjustments in the LCD just to show you a picture. Higher refresh rates mean more changes per second and higher resolutions mean more pixels. There is actually a lot going on just to show even a blank screen.

Comment: An important point that does not seem to be covered yet: monitors paint from top-left to bottom-right almost entirely because we started with CRTs: Display specs are optimized for it, digital film cameras are optimized for it, graphic cards are optimized for it, displays are optimized for it, and so-on. Maybe some time in the future we'll get "centre out" which will be awesome for high-FPS gaming or even parallel render pipelines where every pixel is calculated and sent to the monitor at once, but it would likely take a "throw out the old" approach to do it in the next 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

> Screen tearing is a visual artifact in video display where a display
>   device shows information from multiple frames in a single screen draw.
>   The artifact occurs when the video feed to the device is not in sync
>   with the display's refresh rate.

*Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing).*

All monitors, LCD and CRT, refresh on a clock at a known and predictable time. Various technologies allow the graphics card to know this clock cycle so that the GPU can send data at the best time for the monitor to receive it and display the next screen's-worth of pixels.

This is typically called the refresh rate or on some TVs you'll see a Hz (that is cycles per second) number advertised. The most common these days is probably 60Hz, which means 60 cycles per second. Though 120Hz is become more common.

The various synchronization technologies mentioned above are generally used for the purpose of preventing screen tearing. They usually have limits as to how much they can resolve though.

Comment: This doesn't address my question. See the 3 step "ideal" process I mentioned in my post. If this is what happened, then I don't see how an out of sync refresh rate would cause screen tearing.

Comment: Then it is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking if LCD/LED screens flash an entire screen of pixels at the same instant rather than the progressive scan of a CRT? No, if you point a television video camera (which usually run at a slightly different frame rate at most LCD/LED screens you will see the same tearing/fanning, though usually to a less obvious extent that is further mitigated with higher-frequency screens, you see on CRTs. This should tell you that the pixels on an LCD/LED screen are still being written progressively across the screen in an orderly fashion.

Comment: Ok, yeah, that's what I'm asking. How quickly does this generally happen? (like, time between first pixel changing to last pixel changing?)

Comment: @alecb it will happen at the same rate as the refresh rate of your monitor. for a monitor at 60Hz the refresh rate will be 1/60 = 0.0166 seconds, or every 16 milliseconds.

Comment: This assumes that as soon as the scan finishes bottom-right it begins immediately back up at upper-left. Do we know this is the case?

Comment: "Every 16 ms" doesn't imply that the entire process takes 16ms though, does it? Is this actually the case? Is it specifically slowed to take as long as the refresh rate? Or is the refresh rate basically determined by how quickly the monitor is able to update pixels? Monitors can have different refresh rates though, no?

Comment: Even in 2021 this seems to be a difficult question to answer: How long does it take a monitor to go from drawing the top-left pixel to drawing the bottom-right pixel? The terms are all too generic: "How long for a monitor to draw a frame" results in pages of articles about refresh rate which as we can see is actually a different question. We can see "tearing" as evidence that it takes *some* amount of time to do the full screen, but noone seems to have publicly tackled the specific "how fast" question.

Comment: Different screen technologies have different characteristics and different strengths and weaknesses. As refresh rates rise, the variations become less important to the average person, but for certain niche tasks the differences may still be important. Such a study would be very involved, and likely rather difficult.